# error when I try to fetch calendar events through google API, JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

For some reason; I get error when trying to get my calendar events through google API. I code in JS and use React and have no idea why it does not work.

I have the token stored in sessionStorage and do get personal information about the user like name email and such stuff but I cannot proceed and get the calendar events. Please help!

I'm not sure what exactly you would like to see inside my App but let me know and I'll provide with the stuff because I do not want to upload the whole project lol

https://gyazo.com/37433e19f07e441adf368d1bbcad78e6

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I cannot get my calendar events, 400

Comment: your functions have a different name getEvents and getEvent. with the info you provided, it could be the problem

Comment: No, it is two different functions one on the frontend making AXIOS call to the backend on route /calendar which has that getEvent function in it. Help please :|

sidenote, Moguli da te dodam pa da ti pokazem?

Comment: welcome to SO. You'll need to do much better than "it does not work" in order to receive a successful answer. What are the errors, symptoms, what is sent and received at the http level, what logging have you added to confirm that a call to GDrive is even being made, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to return res.send as you use async/await and it returns promise

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean exactly?
return res.sendStatus(200) in calendar.js ? did not work if that's what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I changed the structure of the app and I do now receive cal events when I hit one of my endpoints, but receiving other kind of error now, anyway this one can be closed.

[Cross-origin request blocked, origin 'null' no access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836261/cross-origin-request-blocked-origin-null-no-access)