# Cross-origin request blocked, origin 'null' no access

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, cors, google-oauth

I'm working on a project where I want to get my calendar events through google API, written in JS and using React.

My question is why do I receive this error? 
I do receive my calendar events but beforehand this error pops up in the console of  the web browser and I've tried it in firefox & chrome.

Chrome err:
https://gyazo.com/bf7687b094c24d0027bcbd4071783b8c

Firefox err:
https://gyazo.com/fa605bc75833d71070acbac34f1275da

This is how my app.js looks like:
https://gyazo.com/f09b6906234c7d65b30ba4f40def1e50

Comment: Check this [Link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) It requires auth token in header to validate the request. Also check this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151068/google-calendar-api-v3-and-ajax-no-access-control-allow-origin-header), its where i found above link.

Comment: "origin null" indicates you are not using a local webserver and simply open your app like `file://..`. Google likely doesn't support that, see https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#avoid-returning-access-control-allow-origin-null - You may need to use a development webserver to have an Origin (and maybe whitelist that somewhere in your Google API account?)

Comment: I'm doing it over localhost and want to render a google login form on my frontend?

Comment: what does whitelist mean, where exactly to do that?

Comment: Taking another look at it, the URL with the error `/o/oauth/v2/auth` seems to be the "Authorize" step of an OAuth2 login. The MIME type `text/html` supports this thesis. You are not supposed to call that via XHR, but rather redirect the user there to login. Maybe you should share the code where this call is made.

Comment: I'm sorry could you please be more specific what is MIME type? how do I know if I redirect via XHR or something else? 

When I press my button this is the code for it and I receive the error in console,
https://gyazo.com/4e3cb3e53ba2d7238376d45bfa672103

Comment: Your error message includes `accounts.google.com`. Nowhere in the code you've shown you have a reference to that nor use a library from Google. We need to see the code related to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require auth key in the preflight OPTIONS request. Add the following line below your cors attachment:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: if you use * will affect secure issue

Comment: I guess, he's developing a PoC. OP can later create the whitelist and narrow down possible addresses.

Comment: @justMe bump anyone

Comment: One question: I guess these two lines are not enough or? In that case, where should I possibly add these auth key in preflight options? I didn't get that part

Comment: Btw isn't pre flight Options for request such as Delete or so? but not for the normal ones get etc. ?

Comment: @den4is, preflight request is a browser machanism preventing you from requesting data from resources with a non-matching origin. Have a read: https://spring.io/understanding/CORS